# TypeError: preprocess() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shave'

Tags: python

```
processed, padhw, shavedim, resized = preprocess(test_image, shave=True)
plt.imshow(resized)
padhw
```

Here is the error code

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-25f398411bf2> in <module>()
----> 1 processed, padhw, shavedim, resized = preprocess(test_image, shave=True)
      2 plt.imshow(resized)
      3 padhw

TypeError: preprocess() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shave'
```

Where should I fix it?

Comment: What is `preprocess` method ? Look at its documentation. There is no thing to *fix*, you provide a non existing parameter as the error says

Comment: I 'm practicing the code of Vehicle Detection at the following link.
[link](https://github.com/ablacklama/Vehicle-Detection/blob/master/Vehicle_Detection.ipynb)

Comment: Verify you import the good elements so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error says, you passed a wrong argument.  I'll suggest you read about the preprocess method and see available arguments. If it's a user defined function, check to see if you added a `shave` parameter